# Why is JavaScript bind() call reversing arguments to function?

Tags: javascript

Binding to oninput event of an `input` element like so:

```
oninput: this.updateNote.bind(event, note)
```

where note is a simple object ({ completed: bool, text: string}) and event is the InputEvent.

I have defined updateNote as follows:

```
updateNote(note, event) {
...
}
```

It works with an oddity I can't explain.

The arguments for updateNote are in reverse order compared to the bind() call, yet note is the correct object and event is the InputEvent.

Comment: The first argument to `.bind` is the new `this` value, not the first argument to pass

Comment: That's true, and furthermore you may be misunderstanding what `.bind()` does. The values you pass to `.bind()` are *actual values* to be passed at the time the bound function is called. You cannot use `.bind()` to reverse the order of parameters to a function, in short.

Comment: It'd probably help if you could explain what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to make sure updateNote() gets all the required information, thus the bind() call. If I simply set the oninput attribute to this.updateNote I wouldn't get both the note and InputEvent values.

Comment: I know the first parameter of bind sets the new ```this``` value, but I am wondering how that translates to updateNote working without issues with the arguments reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
this.updateNote.bind(event, note)   // (1)
```

you create a function `boundFunc` that accepts any number of arguments and calls `updateNote` with `this` equal to whatever the `event` variable happens to contain, one argument `note` and the rest of the args passed to `boundFunc`. So it's basically:

```
event = whatever

function boundFunc(...args) {
    ...updateNote.this = whatever...
    updateNote(note, ...args)
}
```

Now, `onInput` expects a function and calls it with one argument, `event`. Since this function happens to be our `boundFunc`, it's called like this:

```
boundFunc(event)   // (2)
```

and according to the above, "updateNote" is invoked like this

```
updateNote(note, event)
```

which explains the "reversed" thing. Actually, nothing is reversed. The "event" on the line (2) has nothing to do with "event" you've used on the `bind` line (1). *That* one probably contains some rubbish and is lost as long as you don't use `this` in "updateNote".